# Why Python pexpect does not match the expected prompt with newline here

Tags: python, pexpect

I am trying to execute client.py from run.py. The client.py  prompts for an input. I have written a simple pexpect code but it doesn't match the prompt and hangs.

Here is my code

## client.py

```
input = raw_input("Please data, default [ /Anything ]:\n")
if input == "Admin":
    print "Welcome Admin"
else:
    print "Welcom Guest"
```

## run.py

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('python client.py')
child.expect('Please data, default [ /Anything ]:\n')
child.sendline ('anonymous')
```

Here is an another try with expect_exact, it did not help me..

## run1.py

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('python client.py')
child.expect_exact('Please data, default [ /Anything ]:\n')
child.sendline ('anonymous')
```

### Python and pexpect versions -

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, May 13 2014, 12:53:14)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pexpect
>>> pexpect.__version__
'3.2'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use `expect_exact` instead of `expect`, because the later method expects an regular expression, where `[` is a special character.

Comment: It did not work for me.. I have edited my question with the code above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `\n` character. As explained [here](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#find-the-end-of-line-cr-lf-conventions).  You are sending a `\n` but *pexpect* sees that as a `\r\n`, so you have to tell `run.py` to expect `\r\n` instead of just `\n`:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('python client.py')
child.expect_exact('Please data, default [ /Anything ]:\r\n')
child.sendline ('anonymous')
```

Leave the `client.py` just as it is (do not add `\r` to the `raw_input` string there).

Answer (score 0):

You can just have `Anything` in pexpect and then proceed with your code.

```
child.pexpect('Anything')
```